# Laravel dont allow password reset for certain user roles

Tags: laravel

I have setup a password reset in Laravel. I have read through the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passwords but I cant see anywahere if there is a function to only allow the reset password for certain users based on a field in in the database in the users table.

In my users table I have added the field `user_type` if the `user_type` is set to 2 I dont want to allow password reset links being sent for that user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Http/Controllers/Auth/ForgotPasswordController.php` a trait `SendsPasswordResetEmails` is used.

You can override the function `sendResetLinkEmail` in the ForgotPasswordController and add your condition there.

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::where('email', $request->get('email'))->get();
    if (!$user || $user->user_type == 2) {
       return redirect()->back()->with('error' => '...');
    }
    //rest of function
    $this->validateEmail($request);

    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
        $request->only('email')
    );

    return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
                : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Dimitri's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835667/laravel-dont-allow-password-reset-for-certain-user-roles#49836006) is great and correct. Thanks for it.

But there's a way to avoid code duplication: Instead of copying the original code, just call the trait's method when you're done with your custom code.

In your ForgotPasswordController, replace `use SendsPasswordResetsEmails;` with

```
use SendsPasswordResetEmails {
    // make the trait's method available as traitSendResetLinkEmail
    sendResetLinkEmail as public traitSendResetLinkEmail;
}
```

Then write `sendResetLinkEmail` as follows:

```
$this->validateEmail($request);    
$user = User::where('email', $request->get('email'))->get();
if (!$user || $user->user_type == 2) {
   return redirect()->back()->with('error' => '...');
}
// call the original method
return $this->traitSendResetLinkEmail($request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both answers helped with two modifications as follows,

1. use `first()` instead of `get()` as the get method returns an array.

   `$user = User::where('email', $request->get('email'))->get();`
2. change `with` to `withErrors` (don't forget to add missing `[]`)

   `return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['email' => '...']);`